# (How) Can I declare how a field type is to be de-/serialized by Django REST framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using a custom field type in a Django project that is based on `django.db.models.IntegerField` and this type is used for various fields in a model. It is used to store the data as integer in a database while it has a more complex related Python type and string representation. It also implements the methods `value_to_string` and `to_python` that are respected when using `./manage.py dumpdata` for example.

I also exposed a REST API with DRF where a very generic serializer based on `rest_framework.serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` with `fields` configured as `__all__` in its `Meta` object is employed.

When accessing that API a `TypeError` is thrown in `rest_framework.fields.IntegerField.to_representation` when it tries to mangle the aforementioned Python type through `int`.

Now, given that there are de-/serialization routines implemented for that type in question, it's easy to implement a field type (in the DRF meaning, as replacement for the previously mentioned class). But how would I setup a mapping between this field *type* and the Django ORM's one only once without declaring the (DRF) field type for each affected field? I can't find any hint on that in the [serializer fields docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/) nor in the `rest_framework.fields` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom serializer field that corresponds to your model field, and then add that to the mapping that DRF uses for ModelSerializers.

This is how DRF adds the `django.contrib.postgres.fields.*` mappings as well.

- [Creating Custom Serializer Fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields)
- [DRF adding the postgres fields](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1575)

Something like this:

```
class MyField(models.IntegerField):
    pass

class MyDrfField(Field):
    def to_internal_value(...)
    def to_representation(...)

ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[MyField] = MyDrfField
```